# Using list of polygon.txt files in Onedrive to show those files in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, point, text, files

I have many polygon text files of different cities around the  world, I was wondering how I could show these files in ArcGIS Pro. So far I have transferred these files to my C drive, and linked that folder to ArcGIS Pro, however, they show up as text files and not as points or polygons.

How can I get these files to show up as either points or polygons?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the info shown in the .txt in the first screenshot, the text appears to be a list of lists of coordinates (presumably polygon vertices). Can you provided the contents of one of the text files?

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the contents just now